# Вложенный setTimeout/setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval, settimeout

Не могу понять, как работает вложенный setTimeout.

Мне необходимо написать функцию, которая должна будет срабатывать три раза подряд, с одинаковым интервалом, а потом делать одну "паузу" с интервалом чуть, больше. Работать она должна бесконечно. На выходе это должно выглядеть примерно так

```
  (5 сек)
  пауза
    сработка
    (1 сек)
    сработка
    (1 сек)
    сработка
    (1 сек)
  пауза
  (5 сек)
    ...
```

Попробовал написать свою функцию: "паузы" срабатывают корректно, а внутренний цикл (срабатывание) начинает выполняться слишком часто и с каждой новой паузой срабатывает ещё чаще, вот код:

```
    let func1 = () => {
    console.log('Пауза')
    setTimeout(func1, 5000);
    let func2 = () => {
        console.log('Сработка')
        setTimeout(func2, 1666);
    }
    setTimeout(func2, 5000);

}

setTimeout(func1, 5000);
```

Могу предположить, что дело в отсутствующем clearTimeout, но не совсем понимаю как именно он должен работать в данной ситуации

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У Вас `setTimeout(func2, 1666);` внутри `func2` ... каждый раз после запуска - продолжит бесконечно перезапускать саму себя.

Можно сделать, например, так:

```js
let mooo = () => console.log("mooo ^_^");
let bubu = () => console.log("bubu >_<");

/***/

let loop_data = [
  { fn: bubu, times: 1, wait: 3000 }, // Вызвать fn 1 раз, потом ждать 3 секунды,
  { fn: mooo, times: 3, wait: 1000 }, // 3 раза, после вызовов ждать по 1 сек
];

let get_next_obj = (function () {
  // Создает замыкание со всеми данными, необходимыми для получения 
  // очередного объекта из loop_data при каждом вызове
  
  let called_times = 0;
  
  let index = 0;
  let curr_obj = loop_data[index]; // { fn: f_name, times: 1, wait: 3000 }

  return function () { // Переменная get_next_obj получает ссылку на эту функцию      
    console.assert(curr_obj.times >= 1);
    
    if (called_times >= curr_obj.times) {
      // Был вызван достаточное кол-во раз - переключается на следующий объект
      called_times = 0;
      index = (index + 1) % loop_data.length; // зацикливание
      curr_obj = loop_data[index];
    }    
    
    called_times++;
    
    return curr_obj;
  }
})();

/***/
loop();
function loop() {
  let obj = get_next_obj();
  
  obj.fn(); // Вызывает функцию из объекта
   
  setTimeout(loop, obj.wait); // Перезапускает себя через wait миллисекунд
}
```

UPD:

> Как остановить эту шайтан-машину ?

Для управления циклом, можно уже завернуть её в какой-нибудь объект, а-ля:

```js
class Loop {
  constructor(data) {
    this._loop_data = data;
    /* data = [
         {
           fn: {function},
           times: {Int > 0} сколько раз её вызывать (по умолчанию 1),
           wait: {Number} сколько ждать до следующего вызова (ms)
         },
         ...
       ]
     */

    this._curr = {
      obj: data[0],
      index: 0,
      called_times: 0,
    };
    
    this._timeout_id = null;
  }

  _next() {
    /*** Для текущего объекта из _loop_data считает количество вызовов.
    Если его отсюда уже получили .times раз - выдает следующий объект,
    иначе - возвращает текущий ***/
    
    let curr = this._curr;
    let data = this._loop_data;

    if (curr.called_times >= (curr.obj.times || 1)) {
      curr.called_times = 0;
      curr.index = (curr.index + 1) % data.length;
      curr.obj = data[curr.index];
    }

    curr.called_times++;

    return curr.obj;
  }

  _loop() {
    let obj = this._next();

    if (obj.fn) obj.fn(); // { wait: 10000 }
    // Объект, который должен просто ждать, не вызовет ошибку.

    this._timeout_id = setTimeout(() => this._loop(), obj.wait);
    // Использована стрелочная функция, чтобы не потерять контекст this._loop() 
  }

  start() {
    this.stop();
    this._loop();
  }

  stop() {
    clearTimeout(this._timeout_id);
  }

  reset() {
    this._curr.obj = data[0];
    this._curr.index = 0;
    this._curr.called_times = 0;
  }
}

/***/
// Использование:

let bar = document.querySelectorAll(".bar");
let count = 0;
  
function toggle_light() { 
  bar[ (count++ % 12) / 6 | 0 ].classList.toggle("active"); // (*1)
}

let police_lights = new Loop([
  { fn: toggle_light, times: 6, wait: 50 }, // 6 вызовов с задержкой по 50 мс
  { wait: 100 }, // поспать 100 мс
]);

police_lights.start();
```

```css
.bar {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.bar.red.active {
  background-color: red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px red;
}
.bar.blue.active {
  background-color: blue;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar red"></div>
<div class="bar blue"></div>
```

**(*1)** `bar[ (count++ % 12) / 6 | 0 ]`

Есть два блока bar под индексами 0 и 1. Хочется, чтобы функция 6 раз срабатывала для одной, 6 раз для другой

`(count++ % 12)` последовательно дает числа от 0 до 11 включительно. `| 0` — побитовое ИЛИ с нулем. То же, что и Math.trunc(), отбрасывает дробную часть.
Получается целочисленное деление (0...11) на 6: дает или 0, или 1.

Comment: А где функции с именем bubu или dudu?

Comment: @Demon__ Ошибка исправлена))

Comment: Отлично (+1) ;)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, Спасибо, всё как мне нужно. Возник ещё один вопрос, как остановить эту шайтан-машину ? Попробовал завернуть это всё в единую функцию, с именем "mode1" и вне этой функции на button повесить `clearInterval(loop)`, но не помогло

Comment: @Miltosh Обновил ответ, с демо вашей задачи. Вызов `police_lights.stop()` остановит цикл. Но объективно: Не надо изобретать такие "шайтан-машины" если нужно просто что-то переключать у пары блоков) В контексте конкретной задачи, соседние ответы в принципе более уместны.

Answer (score 4):

Вложенный `setTimeout` работает точно так же как и не вложенный.

Давайте разберём как работает приведённый код(были сделаны минимальные изменения в объявлении функций, для удобства чтения):

```
// через 5 секунд вызываем func1
setTimeout(func1, 5000);

function func1() {
  console.log('Пауза')
  // когда произошёл вызов
  // ставим таймер на вызов func1 через 5 сек
  setTimeout(func1, 5000);

  // и сразу же, т.к. js асинхронный, 
  // ставим второй таймер на вызов func2 через 5 сек
  setTimeout(func2, 5000);


  function func2() {
    console.log('Сработка');
    // при вызове функции,
    // мы сразу же ставим таймер на вызов её же через 1.666 секунды
    setTimeout(func2, 1666);
  }

}
```

Соответсвенно, получается ситуация, когда бесконечно множатся таймеры из-за того что при каждом новом вызове `func1`, создаётся новый таймер для `func2` которая в последствии вызывает сама себя.

Если же вы хотите что бы таймеры вызывались последовательно, то и создавать их нужно только тогда, когда закончится предыдущая задача.

Максимально наглядно:

```
setTimeout(func1, 5000);

function func1() {
  console.log("Пауза");

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Сработка 1');
    // ставим таймер на второй вызов только после того как 
    // сработал первый
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Сработка 2');
      // так же и здесь - таймер только после того
      // как сработал предыдущий
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('Сработка 3');
        // идём на следующий круг только
        // после того как выполнили все предудыщие задачи
        setTimeout(func1, 5000);
      }, 1666);
    }, 1666);
  }, 1666);
}
```

Сразу же напрашивается вопрос "Как избавится от лапши из `setTimeout`?".

Как вариант, можно воспользоваться [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) и [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

```
setTimeout(func1, 5000);

async function func1() {

  console.log('Пауза');
  await waitFor(1666);
  func2();

  await waitFor(1666);
  func2();

  await waitFor(1666);
  func2();

  await waitFor(5000);
  func1();

  function func2() {
    console.log('Сработка');
  }
}

function waitFor(msec) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, msec))
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за столь подробный ответ. Я немного переработал свою фунцию и использовал Ваш код с async/await, но из-за особенностей моей программы, всёравно получилось нагромождение повторяющегося кода, можно-ли его как-нибудь оптимизировать ? Возможно стоит использовать setInterval ?
Ссылка на код:
https://jsfiddle.net/esv14n8z/

P.S. "длинная пауза" нужна была для выжидания отработки второго элемента, сейчас программа немного переделана и "длинная пауза" не нужна, хотя всё можно переделать ещё раз)

Comment: @Miltosh, await внезапно работает внутри цикла. Нет надобности создавать несколько функций с полным дублированием кода. Пример: [jsfiddle.net/eohp691g/](https://jsfiddle.net/eohp691g/). Так же имеет смысл белый фон сделать по умолчанию, а цвет уже накидывать через [toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/classList). Последняя пауза лишняя

Answer (score 2):

```js
function f1() { console.log("long pause"); }
function f2() { console.log("short pause"); }

let counter = 0;
function timer() {
  let time = counter++ % 4? (f2(), 1) : (f1(), 3);
  setTimeout(timer, time * 1000);
}

timer();
```